# Drupal Rules to block Spam Bots

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I'm using Drupal 7 with Drupal Commerce for my e-commerce website.
I'm not a new programmer and I can pick up on skills relatively quickly, but I do not do it for a living, so bear with me if this seems like a stupid question.

I'm having difficulty with spam bots filling out my form "Commerce Checkout". Commerce creates a new customer profile (one each for shipping and billing information).

Shipping and Billing information each have the following fields:
First Name
Last Name
Address 1
Address 2
City
State
Zip Code
Country

It's pretty easy to determine which profiles are created by spam bots and which are real. The bot-created profiles have the same string of data in EACH of the above fields.

I'm trying to create a rule using Rules and Rules Form Support modules to BLOCK the creation of the profile or progression through the checkout process if any two of these fields contain the same data, but I'm running into a wall. How can I set up rules in Drupal 7 to accomplish this (i.e. if Address1/Address2 are the same or FirstName/LastName are the same or FirstName/Address1 are the same....)

If there's another way to accomplish this I am open to suggestions. From what I understand, CAPTCHA and Honeypot are really not options for the checkout-process forms because they will not block the progression to the next step. Unless someone is willing to show me how to incorporate one of those as well, that would be great or possibly even easier...

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of modules which can protect your website like

1. Spam Detect: https://www.drupal.org/project/spam_detect
2. Spambot: https://www.drupal.org/project/spambot
3. Simple Anti-spam: https://www.drupal.org/project/simpleantispam
4. User Ip Log: https://www.drupal.org/project/uiplog
5. Restrict Ip: https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_ip
6. IP Ranges: https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_ranges
7. Ban an Ip address: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/ban

and many more.

Use any or any set of such modules to prevent your site from spammers. You can choose which suits you better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just require login with Commerce Checkout Redirect:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect

It will require anonymous users to set up an account first before proceeding.

If you still need more security, you should also be able to follow this suggestion to enable CAPTCHA on your user registration form:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95979/add-captcha-to-registration-form

That should make it possible to reduce the number of spam submissions through your checkout system.